# Invoke Office Script from VBA editor in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, office365, office-scripts, ms-office-script

Is it possible to invoke Office Script directly from the VBA editor in Excel?

Is there an object in Excel that refers to Office Script?

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: Not entirely true. Office Scripts could be invoked via PowerAutomate or LogicApps. All you’d need to do is make the HTTP call from VBA to the flow that runs the script. Now having said that, it’s an extremely roundabout way to do it and it’s not direct but it may still very much achieve the outcome you’re after.